# How do I check if a block has a value in the Tera templating engine used by Zola?

Tags: static-site, static-site-generation, tera, zola

I have a title like this in my Zola (which uses the Tera templating engine) website:

```
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - Newbyte's blog</title>
```

This generates something like this:

```
<title>Birds around the world - Newbyte's blog</title>
```

However, if I don't specify a title in a subtemplate, it generates this:

```
<title> - Newbyte's blog</title>
```

I would like to omit the " - " part if there's no title specified any only generate this

```
<title>Newbyte's blog</title>
```

Is there any way to achieve this in the Tera templating engine? I tried doing this, but it doesn't seem to work. It never generates the " - " part:

```
<title>{% block title %}{% if title %} - {% endif %}{% endblock %}Newbyte's blog</title>
```

Answer (score 4):

i know that in jinja2 you can check if a block is empty by calling `self.block_name()`, but id does not work on zola.

but, i know how to achieve what you want (the title thing).

first, define the title of your page in `config.toml`, on the `title` key (or another, if you wish). Here's an example of the file:

```ini
base_url = "https://blog.dpanovitch.dev"
# this will be the prefix/suffix of the title of all pages
title = "Personal Blog"
description = "Site's description"
default_language = "en"
output_dir = "public"
compile_sass = false
```

then, place the following template on your root html.

```html
{% if page and page.title %}
  {% set title = page.title ~ ' - ' ~ config.title %}
{% else %}
  {% set title = config.title %}
{% endif %}

<title>
  {{ title }}
</title>
```

basically, it checks if the current page (a post, for example) that its rendering has a title defined on the frontmatter. if it does, it sets a variable called `title` to `{page.title} - {config.title}`.

if it does not have that variable, it will use the title defined on your `config.toml`

then, it uses that variable inside the `<title>` tag.

note that this means that you only need to set the page title on the front matter of a markdown file, and not using the block title.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you also mention how to add the variable to the configuration file maybe?

Comment: @Newbyte sorry for the delayed response, i added an example of how the configuration file would look like after adding the variable.